# Слово "импозантный".

Tags: семантика

**Девушки выглядели весьма импозантно: они были одеты в фешенебельные, яркие платья, излучали самые добрые эмоции и весело проводили время на сцене, представляя нашему вниманию свой уникальный номер.**
Скажите, правильно ли употреблено слово в этом предложении? Словарь Ожегова определяет его как "способный импонировать".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Новом словаре иностранных слов о слове ИМПОЗАНТНЫЙ говорится: от фр. imposant -- внушительный, производящий впечатление своим видом, представительный, напр.: импозантный вид, импозантная внешность. (От франц. imposant < imposer ‘импонировать’, восх. к лат. imponere ‘располагать’.)

Такое же толкование дается и в Малом академическом словаре.

В Толковом словаре Ожегова - Шведовой, действительно, появляется толкование 'способный импонировать; представительный (в 3 знач.)'.

Что касается слова ИМПОЗАНТНО, то, на мой взгляд, такое употребление возможно. Никаких стилистических ограничений в словарях нет (кроме того, что слово относится к книжной лексике). Но по моим ощущениям слово ИМПОЗАНТНЫЙ (и ИМПОЗАНТНО) лучше употреблять по отношению к мужчинам: сема 'внушительный, производящий впечатление своим видом, представительный' является главной. Ведь о женщине (как правило!) не говорят: "представительная, внушительная" и под.

Кроме того (это мое личное мнение), мне не очень нравится употребление слова ФЕШЕНЕБЕЛЬНЫЙ по отношению к платью. Да, действительно, фешенебельный - значит 'отвечающий требованиям вкуса, моды, элегантный, изысканный'. Но чаще так говорят о квартире, ресторане, отеле, магазине, курорте, даже об обществе. Но не об одежде. Это звучит как-то слишком на иностранный манер.

Ваше предложение вполне можно перестроить: "Девушки выглядели весьма привлекательно: они были одеты в модные, яркие платья, излучали самые добрые эмоции и весело проводили время на сцене, представляя нашему вниманию свой уникальный номер". Как вам такой вариант?

Comment: Хороший ответ.

Comment: Мне тоже резануло слух слово "фешенебельный", хотя оно, по видимому, связано с англ. fashion «покрой; мода», и франц. façon «фасон, покрой». А эти слова как раз связаны с одеждой!

Comment: В английском есть слово fashionable, что и означает 'модный',  'фешенебельный', 'светский', 'фасонистый'. Налицо влияние английского языка.

Answer (score 0):

слабое слово привлекательный - это для всех. Импозантная женщина - это скорее яркая, изысканная, шикарная, гламурная и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае слово употреблено неправильно. И да, не к каждой женщине применимо слово "импозантная". Это в первую очередь должна быть женщина высокая, породистая (например - Шарлиз Терон, Моника Белуччи, Синди Кроуфорд, Стефани Сеймур, Эль Макферсон, Ясмин Гаури). Ну и обладающая вкусом (на такой не увидишь этих жутких нарощенных ногтей), воспитанная, умная. Когда случайно встречаешься с таким человеком, после ''ах'' и приходит в голову слово "импозантная".